# MATLAB: two S and V vectors, vector S is a subset of the vector V, how to extract vector (V-S) with a simple command

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, subset

I have vector `V` and vector `S`. Vector `S` is a subset of Vector `V`. How can I extract `V-S`, I mean the other subset of vector `V`? Is there a simple command for this in MATLAB?

Comment: Look into [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html).

Comment: @Divakar It worked. Actually, I work in Octave, and `setdiff` is available in Octave too. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Useful info that one!

Comment: @Divakar I'm wondering if you know how to do the same process with Microsoft Excel.

Comment: You need to import the data onto MATLAB with `xlsread` and then use `setdiff`.